# Make a div stay in place while scrolling without its neighbor overlapping it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a div on the left to stay in position as you scroll down the screen, but when I change the position to fixed the div to the right of it shifts position and they overlap each other.  The CSS is below the html. The two divs in question are the #tweet-container and the #friendsnew-tweets. Sorry for the lack of workable code but there are a lot of local files needed to make it all work.

The html is basically (along with the elements inside the two divs in question:

```
<div id=app>
  <div id=feed>
    <div id=update-feed-div> 
       <button id=update-feed></button>
    </div>
    <div id=friends-new-tweets></div>
    <div id=tweet-container<</div>
  </div>
</div>
html, body, #app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Silkscreen;
}
/* Below is the font-family for the imported google font */
    /* font-family: 'Silkscreen', cursive; */

/* .tweet {
  font-family: 'Silkscreen';
} */
#feed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

/* Friends and new tweets div */
#friends-new-tweets {
  width: 25%;
  resize: both;
}

#tweet-container {
  /* border: 4px solid coral; */
  width: 60%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px;
}

.tweet {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  font-family: Silkscreen;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
  font-family: Silkscreen;
  font-size: 3em;
}
/* Innards of the tweets */
.profile-photo {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.username {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.username:hover {
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}

.timestamp {
  grid-column: 3;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: oblique;
  justify-content: end;
}
.message {
  grid-column: 2/ span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  color: green;
}
.icon-container {
  margin: 5px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Update button */
#update-feed {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #1eb036;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#update-feed-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Hover for icons */
.comment:hover {
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}
.retweet:hover {
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}
.like:hover {
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}
.share:hover {
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}
.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Spacing for icons */
.comment {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.retweet {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.like {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.share {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

/* Friends and new tweets div */


/* Friends List */
#friends-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}

#friends-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.friend {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.friend:hover {
  color:rgb(20, 216, 20);
}

/* Tweet forms */


#tweet-form-div {
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  color: rgb(20, 216, 20);
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#message-input {
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;

}
#tweet-submit {
  background-color: #1eb036;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: sticky;` and `top: 0;` to `#feed`.

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5000px;
  /* for demonstration purposes only */
}

#app {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Silkscreen;
}

#feed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* Friends and new tweets div */

#friends-new-tweets {
  width: 25%;
  resize: both;
}

#tweet-container {
  /* border: 4px solid coral; */
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* Update button */

#update-feed {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #1eb036;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#update-feed-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="feed">
    <div id="update-feed-div">
      <button id="update-feed"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="friends-new-tweets"></div>
    <div id="tweet-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```